# css for button and textbox

Tags: html, css

I want to display the button on right side and and textbox as shown in layout. But now I got link this.

[image]
[image: layout]

```css
   .search,
   .add {
     float: right;
     margin-left: 9px;
   }
   .sxt {
     float: right;
   }
```

```html
<input class="stxt" type="text" name="searchtxt">
<a style="padding-right:2ex;"></a>
<button name="search" class="search">Search</button>
```

Comment: You haven't given us enough information. Your code works as it should, the first part of your `CSS` isn't even being used with the `HTML` you provided. Not sure what you want us to do about it when you cannot even provide us with the right code.

Comment: @user3386779 look out your css you mistyped the class name of your input box .

Answer (score 0):

Make some changes in your css and update it like below code

```css
 .search,.add{
 float: left;
margin-left: 9px;
background: #85BD02;
border: 0;
padding: 5px 10px;
border-radius: 5px;
color: white;
}

.sxt{
float: right;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 50%;margin: auto;">
<input class="stxt" type="text" name="searchtxt">
<a style="padding-right:2ex;"></a><button name="search" class="search">Search</button>
    </div>
```

check jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2essewv0/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .search_box{
        width: 180px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .inputbox{
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
    }
    .inputbox input{
        width: 100%;
        height: 25px;
    }
    .search_button{
        float: right;

    }
    .search_button button{
        background-color: #86BE03;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        border: none;
        padding: 4px 4px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
</style>
```

html

```
               <div class="search_box">
                    <div class="inputbox">
                        <input type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="search_button">
                        <button type="submit" value="search">search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite figure out if you wnat the button on the left of the textbox or the right. But for it to be o the left simply change your floats to left and  if you want the button on the right you can remove the floats and it sits correctly with the button to the right of the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Don't float elements, as this may cause issues further down the line in terms of layout/etc.

You can use the default positioning instead (removing float altogether):

```css
.search button {
  height: 30px;
  background: #85BD02;
  border: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
.search input {
  height: 25px;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  box-shadow:none;
}
.search button:hover,
.search input:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" placeholder="seach me" />
  <button>SEARCH</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers render elements next to each other by default unless explicitly mentioned.

In your case you want to have a textbox and a button next to each other with button on right side, so you don't require to include any position specific CSS.

You can simply put your html as

```
<input class="stxt" type="text" name="searchtxt">
<button name="search" class="search">Search</button>
```

and you will notice that the textbox and button are in a flow layout and next to each other.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You mistyped the class name of input text box. You used .sxt but in your html you used class name as .stxt. So just replaced like below your existing CSS style:

```
.stxt{float:right;}
```